How to do image anchoring in OpenGL?
I've looked at:
How do I draw a zoomable image in OpenGL?
and
Scaling and locking SpriteRenderer Image to anchor points
but neither fully helped.
I am making a zoomable image in my OpenGL app. Everything works except that right now it's always anchored at the centre of the image when zooming in or out -- I'd rather have it so that it zooms in on the pixel that's currently in the centre of the window. I've had no luck with the arithmetic, and I was wondering if there's anyone who can help?
The code to initialize the image anchor is relatively easy to understand:
int window_w = 0, window_h = 0;
SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &window_w, &window_h);

int pixels_per_tile = 36;

image_anchor.x = (float(window_w) / 2.0 - pixels_per_tile * float(tiles_per_dimension) / 2.0f);
image_anchor.y = (float(window_h) / 2.0 - pixels_per_tile * float(tiles_per_dimension) / 2.0f);

... which produces this centred image:

However, when I go to update the anchor upon zoom, I don't know what I'm doing. A friend showed me that the correct code when zooming is:
image_anchor.x = window_w / 2.0 - 36.0f * float(tiles_per_dimension) * zoom_factor * view_focus.x;
image_anchor.y = window_h / 2.0 - 36.0f * float(tiles_per_dimension) * zoom_factor * view_focus.y;

... but I don't quite know how to initialize the view_focus vector -- this is a vector that contains numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive, which acts like a target. My problem is that I don't quite know how to set view_focus. It's based off of the pixel in the centre of the window, but I don't quite know how to determine which pixel is in the centre of the window. Any ideas from those who are better than me at arithmetic?
Thank you for your time.
Edit: This is for an open source project -- https://github.com/sjhalayka/tiles
